# MySQL update an AUTO_INCREMENT pk to preserve row ordering

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table with three columns: `id`, `foreign_id`, and `tag`. Queries on this table are ordered first by `foreign_id`, then by `tag`, but we want to deprecate the `tag` column in favor of the more reliable and auto-generated `id`. In doing so, we also need to preserve the ordering data stored in the `tag` column without keeping `tag` around. This ordering only makes sense within the scope of the `foreign_id` column.

To solve this problem, we've decided to update the `id`s within the scope of each `foreign_id` such that the order of the ids preserves the `tag` order information.

How does one update an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key column such that it gets assigned the next value in the counter without changing the rest of the row?

Alternatively, how would one copy an entire row (minus the pk) into a new row and delete the old row?

Comment: If you're asking for the id to be 1-N for each foreign_id, MyISAM may still support that by making the auto_increment field only part of the primary key. I don't think an ALTER would update the values accordingly though. If that is what you're looking for, I could provide a query to update the data after such an ALTER has been performed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxID FROM the_table;
UPDATE the_table SET id = id + @maxID;
SET @i := 0;
UPDATE the_table SET id = (@i := @i + 1) ORDER BY foreign_id, tag;
```

I am not 100% positive this will work; I don't usually do this kind of things with UPDATE statements. Alternatively, you could replace that last UPDATE with:

```
INSERT INTO the_table(id, foreign_id, tag) 
SELECT (@i := @i + 1) AS `new_id`, foreign_id, tag 
FROM the_table 
ORDER BY foreign_id, tag
;
DELETE FROM the_table 
WHERE id >= @maxID
;
```

In either case, this assumes current `id` values are always >= 0.